# Detect UIAlert / Notification

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uialertview

I'm using Cocos2D to write a game for iOS. I have implemented a pause feature that allows the user to a pause menu on request. I also implement a complete pause (unschedule main game loop) when receiving a `applicationWillResignActive`. On `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` I resume the main game loop, but then throw the player into the pause menu, forcing them to resume when ready. Everything seems to be working well except for one situation. When receiving a calendar event alarm (which I assume is a UIAlert), the game does not throw up a pause menu or pause the game.

My three questions: must I include both `willEnterForeground` and `didBecomeActive`, or is one good enough for my purposes? What is the call I must schedule for to receive UIAlerts (if that is in fact what triggers my error in the above case) and how should I handle them? Is there some way to simulate a UIAlert so I can test/debug?

Much appreciated.

---

Edit -

The problem was in my overall handling of said events. As -clearly- stated in apple's documentation, use `willResignActive` to pause the game (i.e. throw up a pause menu and stop the game loop), and `didEnterForeground` to resume the game loop, but keep the pause menu up. By handling the events this way, there was no need to schedule to receive UIAlerts or Local/Remote Notifications.

Comment: I think this is the appropriate use for `applicationWillResignActive:` in the `UIApplicationDelegate`  I'm not positive though, the documentation isn't 100% clear.  It just states: "This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state."

Comment: I agree, it's very ambiguous. Also, I cannot tell if I'm supposed to set an observer to receive local/remote notifications or not... unclear.

Comment: You don't need an observer but a UIApplicationDelegate that implements this message (usually the AppDelegate class). If you're not sure, just implement ALL delegate messages and set a breakpoint or add logging so you'll know when which of the messages is received.

Comment: How might I implement such a delegate with Kobold2D if I really only want a 'GameState' scene to handle such interruptions?

Comment: Once again, PEBKAC. I sat down and re-read the apple's programming guide documentation. Some day I'll stop asking such naive questions.

Comment: Is the calendar alert you're talking about a banner or a popup alert? I don't think Apple provides a way to tell when a banner pops up, because it's apparently unintrusive enough for the app to be able to continue.

Comment: @PartiallyFinite my issue was that I thought (wrongly) that I would need to handle some notifications differently than others in terms of pausing the game. You are correct in that a banner pop-up will not interfere with the game.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you will get a calendar event you will get a call of applicationWillResignActive: , this is a place to handle cocos2D pause or any-other thing you want to do at calendar event reception. If calender event ignored applicationDidBecomeActive will be called. If not ignored then you will have to resume from same you are doing.